# How do I write all-but-one function in Scheme/LISP?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, scheme

Can you guys think of the shortest and the most idiomatic solution to all-but-one function?

```
;; all-but-one
;; checks if all but one element in a list holds a certain property
;; (all-but-one even? (list 1 2 4)) -> true
;; (all-but-one even? '(1)) -> true
;; (all-but-one even? '(2 4)) -> false
```

Edit: all but EXACTLY one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a better name:

```
(define (all-except-one pred l) (= 1 (count (negate pred) l)))
```

(But this is PLT specific.)

Comment: nice. i didnt know about (count pred list) .

Answer (score 5):

If the first element has the specified property, call `all-but-one` on the remainder of the list.

If the first element does not have the specified property, call `all` on the remainder of the list.

Comment: Nice solution, but I have to ask (I'm a relative LISP newb compared to most LISPers) if the recursion will be optimized away?

Comment: Define optimized away. In general, no, it'll remain recursive. Lisp as an idea has no concept of the optimization or anything. A single implementation/interpreter may implement Tail Call Optimization which would effectively make this code iterative, yes. :)

Comment: The tail-call optimization is what i was referring to. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Anthony Kanago: Scheme very much has a concept of tail-call optimization: http://www.cs.grinnell.edu/courses/Scheme/r5rs-html/r5rs_22.html

Comment: Anthony was talking about LISP and not Scheme. Could Anon write  a code so that I could profile it?

Comment: Are you asking me to turn it into code because you are unable to, or is it just because you're lazy?

Comment: Shuldn't it be the opposite of what you have written?

If first element does not have property then call `all`.
If first element does have property then call `all-but-one`.

Comment: You are correct. That is how I had it originally - I must have become confused somewhere and changed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The PLT solution is elegant, and ordinarily I prefer to use built-in higher-order functions as opposed to writing my own recursive functions.  But if you want an efficient recursive solution with no allocation and no arithmetic, here it is:

```
(define (all-but-one pred l)
  (if (null? l) 
     #f
     ((if (pred (car l)) all-but-one all) pred (cdr l))))
```

The recursive call is in tail position, so both Scheme and Common LISP will compile this code into a tight loop.  Some people might prefer this equivalent code:

```
(define (all-but-one pred l)
  (if (null? l) 
     #f
     (if (pred (car l))
        (all-but-one pred (cdr l))
        (all pred (cdr l)))))
```

Comment: The "tight loop" is still there in the H.O. version, `count` is doing that just fine.  The main extra cost would come from wrapping the predicate.  (And BTW, Common Lisp in general will not optimize it to a loop, only some compilers will.)

Comment: @Eli: Agreed.  It's just that count does some arithmetic.  Since arithmetic is basically free, I should not obsess over it.  Does Common LISP not guarantee proper tail calls?

Comment: Since the introduction of the JIT in PLT, arithmetics became extremely cheap.  (As for CL -- many people suffer from the "bad for debugging" opinion...)

Answer (score 2):

Common Lisp:

```
(defun all-but-one-p (predicate sequence)
  (= 1 (count-if-not predicate sequence)))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 92 > (all-but-one-p #'evenp '(1 2 3))
NIL

CL-USER 93 > (all-but-one-p #'evenp '(1 2 4))
T
```

This LOOP-based version quits early if more than one element delivers a negative result for the predicate.

```
(defun all-but-one-p (predicate list)
  (= 1 (loop with not-pred = (complement predicate)
             for item in list count (funcall not-pred item) into counter
             when (> counter 1) do (return-from all-but-one-p nil)
             finally do (return counter))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (all-but-one p? xs)
  (= (length (filter p? xs)) (- (length xs) 1)))
```

OK, how about this: not so short, but just one pass over the list.  You could do the same sort of thing using a fold.

```
(define (all-but-one p? xs)
  (let loop ((len 0) (sat 0) (tmp xs))
    (if (null? tmp)
        (= sat (- len 1))
        (loop (+ len 1)
              (if (p? (car tmp)) (+ sat 1) sat)
              (cdr tmp)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

generalized Anon's idea.

```
(define (all-but-n n pred lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      (zero? n)
      (if (pred (car lst))
          (all-but-n n pred (cdr lst))
          (if (zero? n)
              #f
              (all-but-n (- n 1) pred (cdr lst))))))

(define (all-but-one pred lst) (all-but-n 1 pred lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that should work on all decent Scheme implementations:

```
(define (all-but-one? pred values)

  (define (count-neg x)
    (if (not (pred x)) 1 0))

  (let loop ((c 0) (values values))
    (if (and (not (null? values))
         (<= c 1))
    (loop (+ c (count-neg (car values))) (cdr values))
    (= c 1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (all-but-one? p ls)
  (define (all? ls)
    (or (null? ls)
        (and (p    (car ls))
             (all? (cdr ls))))
  (define (loop ls)
    (cond ((null? ls)   #f)
          ((p (car ls)) (all? (cdr ls)))
          (else         (loop (cdr ls)))))
  (loop ls))
```